# How to replace text within parenthesis in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some data with parenthetical I want to remove. I know the following piece of code works to remove the parenthetical. I just want to understand what exactly it's doing. What does the `r` do? How about the `\`? I know the `.*` stands for any number of characters between the parenthesis.

```
df['name'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

Comment: You should review regular expressions. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html) is a good resource. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) are good, too.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used pandas before, however a quick lookup indicates that the `r` prior to the String literal indicates that you're applying a RegEx pattern as opposed to replacing a literal.

As far as the RegEx, here it is broken down:
`\(.*\)`

- `\(` Escapes the open parenthesis character to match it literally
- `.*` Matches any character except for line breaks zero or more times
- `\)` Escapes the close parenthesis character to match it literally